# Connection timeouts are not as expected

Tags: http, python-requests, python-3.8, urllib3

I am trying to handle connection timeouts with a specific api, I mock that by trying to request on a host and a port that I know wont be responding nor actively refusing the connection.

The problem is that there seem to be a factor that causes the timeout periods to take double the time that is expected and I can't figure out why or get to the bottom of it.

Here is an example showcasing the problem:

```py
import time
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import urllib3
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import http
import socket


def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            end_time = time.time()
            execution_time = end_time - start_time
            print(e)
            print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds\n")
            return
        end_time = time.time()
        execution_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper

@timer
def req_via_session(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(total=0, connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    session.get(url, timeout=2, allow_redirects=False)

@timer
def req_via_urllib(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager(retries=False, timeout=urllib3.Timeout(connect=2, read=1.0))
    response = http.request('GET', url)

@timer
def req_via_http_client(host, port, endpoint):
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host, port=port, timeout=2)
    conn.disable_retries = True
    conn.request("GET", endpoint)
    response = conn.getresponse()

@timer
def req_via_sock(host, port):
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)[0]
    family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr = addr
    sock = socket.socket(family, socktype, proto)
    sock.settimeout(2)
    sock.connect(sockaddr)
    
# url = 'https://10.0.0.1:4343'
url = 'https://localhost:80'
req_via_session(url)
req_via_urllib(url)
req_via_http_client(*url.strip('https://').split(':'), '/')
req_via_sock(*url.strip('https://').split(':'))
```

Output:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DDEE079C30>, 'Connection to localhost timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))
Execution time: 4.0154197216033936 seconds

(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DDEF3141F0>, 'Connection to localhost timed out. (connect timeout=2)')
Execution time: 4.009862422943115 seconds

timed out
Execution time: 4.012278318405151 seconds

timed out
Execution time: 2.0100672245025635 seconds
```

This is not the case if I try a url such as `https://10.0.0.1:4343` in which all functions will timeout in 2 seconds as expected.

**EDIT**: Changing the host to be an ip-address "127.0.0.1" instead of a hostname "localhost" results in the correct connection-timeout spans, it seems this problem has something to do with a step where the hostname gets resolved, it seems as if a connection configured with the timeout, is attempted twice if a hostname is involved.